# From SQL one-to-many to Parse NoSQL

Tags: javascript, database-design, parse-platform, nosql

I have always used MySQL for database and seeing that joins are *twisted* with Parse API for NoSQL, I believe I have a flaw with the design of my database.

Here is what I use :

```
Game
---------
id
userA
userB
currentRound


RoundScore // A Game can have 0-3 RoundScore
---------
id
game -> Pointer field to Game
user
round
score
```

(There is also a default User collection with Parse and all user-related fields inside Game and RoundScore point to the User collection. This works great).

Seeing how the Parse API works, I found it difficult to make the query :

***Get all `Games` and their (up to 3) `Rounds' score` where `Game.userA = me` or `Game.userB = me`.***

I could easily get all Games but without their `Rounds' score`. I can't join both.

How should I handle this query or the design ?
Should I fuse the RoundScore into the Game collection ? If so, how should I declare the new field ?

Answer (score 1):

I have read all these pages:

- https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries
- https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-achieve-or-condition-in-query
- https://parse.com/questions/combining-queries-or-not-and-modeling-relationships
- https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html

I am of the opinion that the following code snippet should work for you:

```
var RoundScoreQuery = new Parse.Query("RoundScore");

var userAQuery = new Parse.Query("Game");
userAQuery.equalTo("userA", "me");

var userBQuery = new Parse.Query("Game");
userBQuery.equalTo("userB", "me");

var gamesQuery = Parse.Query.or(userAQuery, userBQuery);

gamesQuery.find({
  success: function(results) {
     // results contains all games where "me" is a part of
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

      var gameId = results[i].get("id");
      RoundScoreQuery.equalTo("game", gameId);

      query.first({
        success: function(object) {
          // Successfully retrieved the object with the score
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // There was an error.
  }
});
```

Comment: In your code, you do as much queries as there are games found. If I retrieve 100 games, I will have 100 queries for RoundScore and this is very expensive :S Well, at least it works ^^ But I would like to use a single query to retrieve everything

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that's a good point.
I would create the Game Object like this (https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects):

```
var id = 1; // game #1
var userA = "Name A";
var userB = "Name B";
var score1 = { user: "Name A", score: 3 }; // round one
var score2 = { user: "Name B", score: 5 }; // round two
var score3 = null; // round three

var Game = Parse.Object.extend("Game");
var game = new Game();
game.set("id", number);
game.set("userA", userA);
game.set("userB", userB);
game.set("ScoreR1", object);
game.set("ScoreR2", object);
game.set("ScoreR3", object);
game.save();
```

The flag "currentRound" is no longer needed
because you know what's the current round is 
when you look at ScoreR1, ScoreR2 and ScoreR3.

Now you should only need this code to get all the games where "me" is part from:

```
var userAQuery = new Parse.Query("Game");
userAQuery.equalTo("userA", "me");

var userBQuery = new Parse.Query("Game");
userBQuery.equalTo("userB", "me");

var gamesQuery = Parse.Query.or(userAQuery, userBQuery);

gamesQuery.find({
  success: function(results) {
    // results contains all games where "me" is a part of
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // There was an error.
  }
});
```

For more info about "NoSQL Design Patterns for Relational Data", I would recommend this article:
http://robvolk.com/designing-for-relationships-on-a-no-sql-database/

Answer (score 1):

2 ways of doing this:

use pointers from 'game' to 'score' so that you can flatten the query with ['include=' syntax](https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-retrieving).

Note they even use "games" in the docs example!

Or leverage noSql arrays to flatten your physical design:

```
Game
---------
id
userA -> type:Array:"scores":["123","234","345"]  <-- handle null array
userB -> type:Array:"scores":["321","242","325"]
```

Just say the Game scores are an array that belong to "game/user"

Just say Game consists of 2 sets of "userScores" which are arrays

IMO you want to come up with a noSql compatible way of dealing with your models and their collections in your MVC mechanism so you can always template it neatly by coming out of your Parse.com API calls with JSON structs that you can easily parse and feed appropriate JSON Objects to whatever template you use for ( JSON to model Obj Classes & Collections ).

[example i guess](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) even tho java it may give idea for ios